# How to close additional R sessions when parallel computing is completed using doFuture package?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, future

I'm trying to use `doFuture` package for parallel computing. Here is the code from the document of the package.

```r
library(doFuture)
plan(multisession)

cutoff <- 0.10
y <- foreach(x = mtcars) %dofuture% {
  mean(x, trim = cutoff)
}
names(y) <- colnames(mtcars)
```

When the computing is completed, the additional R sessions for parallel computing are not closed. When I use `doParallel` package, I use the following to make cluster

```r
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

and use the following code to stop cluster.

```r
closeCluster(cl)
```

How do I close these R sessions when using the `doFuture` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the plan to `sequential()` will close the extra R sessions.

```
plan(sequential)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But this solution is unexpected.